# For textbox can we have file path validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to check the path that i have specified in textbox is correct or not.

i.e. means a validation needed to suggest us to find that what you have entered in the textbox is correct or not.

Path validation in textbox can we have...............

Comment: Do you mean syntactically valid, that is, having a form that could be a file? Or do you mean valid from existence, that is, because the path in the textbox actually exists?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool r = ValidFilePath(txtPaySlipPDFTemplatePath.Text);
private bool ValidFilePath(string path)
{  
   String pattern = @"^(([a-zA-Z]\:)|(\\))(\\{1}|((\\{1})[^\\]([^/:*?<>""|]*))+)$";    
   Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);    
   return reg.IsMatch(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "a correct path"? Anyway you can add a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) control in your page, in whose code behind use some code like this:

```
pathValidator.ServerValidate += (sender, args) =>
    {
        args.IsValid = Directory.Exists(myTextBox.Text);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid paths change depending on the file system you're using.
Something like this can test whether or not the path is valid

```
public bool IsValidPath(String path, bool requiresFullPath = true)
{
    try
    {
        if(requiresFullPath && !path.Contains(":"))
            return false;

        Directory.GetLastAccessTime(path);
        return true;
    } catch (ArgumentException) { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your regular expression don't works in the case of two slashes in the Path as in the next sample:

```
string Path = "\\\192.168.0.1\folder\folder2\folder3\\\file.pdf";
```

Comment: This answer should be a comment on the answer for which it's relevant, not a separate answer.